# how to override css height using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here I am using a css file where I am setting height for tootltip

```
.md-tooltip{
   width : 120px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color:white;
 }
```

dynamically trying to set the height using

```
 $(".md-tooltip").height(100);
```

how to override the height 100px from CSS file. I want the height to need to be set by $ jquery. It's not working currently.

**EDIT**

```js
$(".md-tooltip").height(50);
```

```css
.md-tooltip{
   width : 120px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color:red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class=md-tooltip></p><br>
```

Comment: There is no problem with `$(".md-tooltip").height(100);`, are you sure that this code is wrapped inside a `$(document).ready(...`?

Comment: Did you add the jquery library? @NandhiniPriya

Comment: @NandhiniPriya why you are adding height in css if you want to add it dynamically?

Comment: Let me know is there any way i can do

Comment: @NandhiniPriya just add height dynamically as you are adding remove the height from CSS. I think it will work.

Comment: @NandhiniPriya and remove java from tags there is no java in the question.

Comment: Don't you need a measurement unit? `.height("100px");`?  Also, is this element `display: block`?

Comment: $(".md-tooltip")[0].style.setProperty('height', '100px', 'important');

Comment: @NandhiniPriya, you can set important with setProperty

Comment: @zero298 A measurement unit is optional. The function takes an integer or a string. If passed an integer, jQuery assumes pixels as the measurement.

Answer (score 3):

`$(".md-tooltip").css("height","100px");` should work for you. EDIT: if you have a variable, put it like this: (" css attr.name", var+"px")

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result , use below option of setProperty

```
$(".md-tooltip")[0].style.setProperty('height', '100px', 'important');
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rdLVBy

**Option2:**
Using attr() option ,add style

```
$(".md-tooltip").attr('style','height: 50px !important');
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NYrGWj

Comment: trust this man, is faster method because of pure js (part after selector)

Comment: If you are going to take the pure js route, why not do the whole thing: `document.getElementsByClassName('post-text')[0]`...

Comment: yes @War10ck, that works too , updated my answer in jquery way different option :)